# DBProj.dbschema(0,0): Warning SQL01271: The unnamed foreign key between tables X and Y will be checked by checking the table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, create-table, visual-studio-dbpro

I received this error while deploying a Visual Studio SQL Server DBProject

> DBProj.dbschema(0,0): Warning SQL01271: The unnamed foreign key
>   between tables [dbo].[Match] and [dbo].[Team] will be checked by
>   checking the table.  Name the foreign key to avoid checking the entire
>   table and only check the new constraint.

My table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Match]
(
    MatchID         int identity(11,2) PRIMARY KEY, 
    TournamentID    int not null REFERENCES Tournament(TournamentID),
    Team1_ID        int not null REFERENCES Team(TeamID),
    Team2_ID        int not null REFERENCES Team(TeamID),
    MatchDate       date,
    MatchTime       time
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Team]
(
    TeamID    int PRIMARY KEY,
    TeamName  varchar(50)
)
```

> **UPDATE:** [Unnamed constraints](http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-drop-unnamed-constraint-in-sql-server.asp)
>
> If you do not specify a name, SQL will generate a random name built from a prefix which denotes the type of constraint, and
>   partial table and column names followed by a random alphanumeric
>   string. It would normally look something like this:
>   DF_*MyTable*_MyColu__3F3159AB
>
> Everytime the DBProject is rebuilt and deployed this process is
>   repeated generating a new set of random constraint names

What does this error means? What is the implication? Especially, **Name the foreign key to avoid checking the entire table and only check the new constraint.**

Comment: Can you add the [dbo].[Team] definition as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Summary:** It is best practice to always name constraints

Information about this question, for me, is hard to come by. So far, I have been able to find some new information on constraints and I can say I have learnt more.

Posting this same question on dba.SE.com and [I got this response](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/warning-sql01271-the-unnamed-foreign-key-between-tables-dbo-match-and-dbo)

> [How To Drop An Unnamed Constraint in SQL Server](http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-drop-unnamed-constraint-in-sql-server.asp)
>
> If you do not specify a name, SQL will generate a random name built
>   from a prefix which denotes the type of constraint, and partial table
>   and column names followed by a random alphanumeric string. It would
>   normally look something like this:
>
> ```
> DF__MyTable__MyColu__3F3159AB
> ```

.

> [Cleaning Up SQL Server Deployment Scripts](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/cleaning-up-sql-server-deployment-scripts/) in the *DRI Objects
>   with "Junk" names* section
>
> For example, if a Primary Key is created but left unnamed, SQL Server
>   uses a default auto-generated name, PK__TableName__Junk (for example,
>   PK__Customer__A4AE64082CE326F2). This will cause SQL Compare to drop
>   the Primary Key and recreate it, because the Junk portion of its name
>   will be different on different databases.
>
> This means that even though there has been no functional change, any
>   change scripts generated using comparison software will, **upon every
>   new build, attempt to remove the 'old' constraint and add the 'new'
>   one. Dropping and recreating a primary key on a table can be a very
>   costly operation** and since there has been no functional change, one
>   that we can well live without.

.

> [Dan Jones blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2009/10/29/best-practice-naming-constraints.aspx): **Best Practice: Naming Constraints**
>
> The bottom line is don’t be a lazy DBA/Programmer and let the system
>   name your constraints. The few extra taps on the keyboard will be
>   worth it in the long run.
>
> In fact, this might become part of my standard arsenal of DBA interview questions: do you name your constraints? Or something like that.